# Razor Intellisense in .NET4.7.2 "PackageReference" project?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I have all my references setup to "PackageReference" and it works and builds fine but I don't have intellisense with Razor. I can't move to .netcore, but it builds and runs fine I just lose a lot with intellisense. I guess I can do the "choose" switch in the csproj to point it to DLLs, but what is the bare minimum that I need to get intellisense to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All my references setup to "PackageReference"

How do you handle the references like `system`, `system.web`?

We should only need to change the format of Hintpath in xx.csproj(assemblies from nuget), and keep other things the same. If this is actually what you did, close vs=>delete the hidden `.vs` folder in Solution folder=>restart vs and reload the project to check if Intellisense can work now.

**In addition:** It's not officially supported to migrate `asp.net full framework` projects from `packages.config` to `PackageReference` format. For me, I use this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CloudNimble.NuGetPackageReferenceUpgrader) in VS2017 to make this job for me, you can give it a try. And there's [one discussion about the official support](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246759/migrate-packagesconfig-to-packagereference-not-ava.html) for that migration in DC, you can vote for it and track the latest info there.